# How do i pass a variable from a form to a javascript constructor?

Tags: javascript, forms, constructor

instead of calling `sum()` and defining variables inside of the function, how can i tell a form to pass its data to the function

```
onclick="sum(N)"
```

**The goal of this exercise is to understand javascript constructors.**

here is an example of what i've tried. 
The output should be 50 + N, but i just get 50.

```
Enter a Number
<input type="number" id="number">
<button onclick="sum(N)">submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  N = document.getElementById("number").value

  function sum(N){

    var a = N + 50;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;

  }
</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<button onclick="sum(N)">submit</button>
```

to:

```
<button onclick="sum(document.getElementById('number').value)">submit</button>
```

and get rid of this:

```
 N = document.getElementById("number").value
```

You need to pass the value from the `input` to your `sum()` function when the button is clicked...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can work with `n`, but only if it is a reference.

```js
var n = document.getElementById("number");

function sum(n) {
    var a = +n.value + 50;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
Enter a Number: <input type="number" id="number">
<button onclick="sum(n)">submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```